# How to create a post-build script for all Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to create a post build script for all Jenkins jobs? Some script that is shared across jobs? I would like to avoid manually creating a post-build script for each job if possible.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no job that will always run after any other job. You can emulate that creating a new job and then either configure a post build trigger on all your jobs to run the new one, or configure a build trigger in the new job to run after all the jobs you specify.

However, if all your jobs are pipelines and you have a shared library you can create a step that is actually a pipeline with a built-in `post`, for example consider a step called `postPipeline.groovy`:

```
def call(Closure body) {
  pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage('Run pipeline') {
        steps {
          script {
            body()
          }
        }
      }
    }
    post {
      always {
        << routine post actions go here >>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By changing all the pipelines to use this step you ensure they all run the post script:

```
postPipeline {
  stage('Pipeline stage') {
    << code >>
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Still, in any case you get yourself involved in manual labor.